# Shared tooltip with multiple stacks

Tags: highcharts

I've implemented a stacked column chart with 4 series divided over 2 stacks. I want to create a tooltip for each stack that only shows info for the series that belong to that stack. When I use `shared: true` option for the tooltip formatter function, I get all the series in the `$.each(this.points, function(i, point) {})` loop.

How can I create a tooltip for each stack, while still having access to all the series in the stack?

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use formatter and the loop which get data y value.

http://jsfiddle.net/3Utat/10/

```
tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            var indexS = this.series.index,
                indexP = this.point.x,
                series = this.series.chart.series,
                out = 'y1:' + this.y + '<br/>';

            switch (indexS) {
                case 0:
                    out += 'y2: ' + series[1].data[indexP].y;
                    break;
                case 1:
                     out += 'y2: ' +series[0].data[indexP].y;
                    break;
                case 2:
                     out += 'y2: ' +series[3].data[indexP].y;
                    break;
                case 3:
                     out += 'y2: ' + series[2].data[indexP].y;
                    break;
            }

            return out;
        }
        },
```